# OpenGL / GLFW appear transparent

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, glfw

While drawing a simple cube using opengl and glfw, the faces of the cube appear to be transparent.
Here's the code. Use the arrow keys to rotate. I've just encapsulated into a class, in my program.
Using Visual C++ Ultimate 2010.

```
#include "GAME.h"
using namespace std;
GAME::GAME() 
{
    glfwInit();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); 
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0); 
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1); 
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE); 
}
int GAME::execute() 
{
    glfwOpenWindow(640, 320, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, GLFW_WINDOW);
    glfwSetWindowTitle("Viraj");
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(events);
    running = true;
    while(glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        loop();
        render();
    }
    return 0;
}
void GAME::events(int key, int action)
{
    switch(key)
    {
    case GLFW_KEY_UP:
        glRotatef(10, 1, 0, 0);
        break;
    case GLFW_KEY_DOWN:
        glRotatef(-10, 1, 0, 0);
        break;
    case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT:
        glRotatef(10, 0, 1, 0);
        break;
    case GLFW_KEY_LEFT:
        glRotatef(-10, 0, 1, 0);
        break;
    }
}
int GAME::loop()
{
    return 0;
}
int GAME::render()
{
    int win_width;
    int win_height;
    glfwGetWindowSize(&win_width, &win_height);
    const float win_aspect = (float)win_width / (float)win_height;
    glViewport(0, 0, win_width, win_height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //glOrtho(-win_aspect, win_aspect, -1., 1., -1., 1.);
    gluPerspective(90, win_aspect, 1, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 3.0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); 
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0); 
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1); 
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glRotatef(-1, 0, 1, 0);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //Front
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //Left
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    //Back
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    //Right
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    //Top
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, -0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    //Bottom
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);

    glEnd();
    glfwSwapBuffers();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Do they appear transparent and you don't want them to (would be indeed strange)? Or do you want them to appear transparent and you don't know how (would be worded a bit strange)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you, but your code is broken on several levels. Let me break it down for you:

```
#include "GAME.h"
using namespace std;
GAME::GAME() 
{
    glfwInit();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); 
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0); 
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1); 
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE); 
}
```

Here lies the first error: GLFW is a C library, and it needs to be initialized exactly **once**. The call to `glfwInit()` belongs into the main function, not a class constructor. The other function calls are OpenGL calls, however they require an active OpenGL context. At this point of the program there is no OpenGL context however, so all the calls you do have not effect at all.

```
int GAME::execute() 
{
    glfwOpenWindow(640, 320, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, GLFW_WINDOW);
    glfwSetWindowTitle("Viraj");
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

Again the nature of GLFW doesn't go along with being used as part of a class. You can have only one window in GLFW and there's only one event loop. This doesn't map so well to classes and objects. You can have of course a class `EventLoop` or similar, but you wouldn't use it like that.

And then there is this next one line I'm surprised it actually compiled:

```
    glfwSetKeyCallback(events);
```

`events` if a member function of class `GAME`, and unless this is a static member function, you can not use a class member function as callback, especially not to a C library, which doesn't know classes. How should it know, which instance that event function belongs to? C++ doesn't have the concept of *closures* or *delegates*, which was required for this (other languages do, for that very reason).

```
    running = true;
    while(glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        loop();
        render();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What comes now is a classical newbie misconception:

```
void GAME::events(int key, int action)
{
    switch(key)
    {
    case GLFW_KEY_UP:
        glRotatef(10, 1, 0, 0);
        break;
    case GLFW_KEY_DOWN:
        glRotatef(-10, 1, 0, 0);
        break;
    case GLFW_KEY_RIGHT:
        glRotatef(10, 0, 1, 0);
        break;
    case GLFW_KEY_LEFT:
        glRotatef(-10, 0, 1, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

The matrix manipulation calls make only sense withing the drawing code. Calling glRotate here will just mess with the matrix stack, but every sane OpenGL rendering function will initialize all state so some sane values at the beginning.

What you want to do in a event handler is accumulating all input into variables, which you later use in the drawing code to setup and control rendering.

```
int GAME::loop()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If this is meant to loop, why is there no loop?

```
int GAME::render()
{
    int win_width;
    int win_height;
    glfwGetWindowSize(&win_width, &win_height);
    const float win_aspect = (float)win_width / (float)win_height;
```

Only one detail missing: You need to set the viewport here. No big deal: `glViewport(0, 0, win_width, win_height);`

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //glOrtho(-win_aspect, win_aspect, -1., 1., -1., 1.);
    gluPerspective(90, win_aspect, 1, 100.0);
```

*Now this is actually good!* You do setup the projection matrix in the render function. Way to go, stick to this pattern!

**UPDATE** However the next line is wrong:

```
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 3.0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

`gluLookAt` is a function meant to be performed on the **modelview** matrix. The modelview matrix is responsible for both placing models in world space and aligning the world to the view, hence the transformation are `model→world, world→view` of which you can reduce away the interim `world` step so it's only `model→view`.

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Here you would call `glLoadIdentity(); gluLookAt(...);`. It should become obvious now, why doing matrix manipulations in event handlers makes no sense.

You should actually set the modelview matrix, with all transformations done from scratch here.

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

It's a bit unusual to call `glClear` after setting up the matrices, viewport, etc., but not wrong. You may leave it that way.

However before you begin rendering, you should, acutually *must* set all OpenGL state required. Remember those "initializing" OpenGL calls in the constructor. They belong **here**.

```
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //Front
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //Left
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    //Back
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    //Right
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    //Top
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    //Bottom
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);

    glEnd();
```

If you want lighting you need to supply normals. But I'd not bother adding a large bunch of `glNormal` calls up there: The Immediate Mode (glBegin, glEnd) is outdated, I strongly recommend you learn about Vertex Arrays and Vertex Buffer Objects.

```
    glfwSwapBuffers();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Summarizing: Get the GLFW calls out of the class. GLFW is not object oriented. Just use it globally from the `main` function. Passing events to classes is in order, but you can't use class member functions as callbacks to GLFW. You need to write some helper function

```
extern GAME *pGame;
void eventhandler(int key, int action)
{
    pGame->event(key, action);
}
```

You may also have the `GAME` class manage a static list of all instances and provide a static member function, that passes the event to all instances in the list. Or use a singleton (however I think singletons are an anti pattern, and should be avoided).

Comment: W-O-W. I'd +5 this if I could! the events function is static which is why it compiles. I asked a different question about that.

Comment: Edited the code of the render function. Rotating doesn't work. Is it because gluLookat resets the eye perspective ?

Comment: @viraj: Indeed, Like I explained, you should not do glRotate from the event handler, since anything done there will be reset by a properly written render function. Store the outcome of events in some variables, use them to apply the transformation in the render code.

Comment: @viraj: Using static member functions for C callback is not good style – and misleading. You shouldn't do it. But this is not a OpenGL question, but a question about good OOP design with C++. It would make sense if there were delegates in C++, which is doesn't. So please don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not sure what the question is (do they really appear transparent?), the obvious first spot in your code is, that you enable lighting, but you don't specify any normal vectors for your vertices. These are needed to tell OpenGL what direction a vector faces (how the actual surface of the object is oriented, but at each discrete vertex).

But in your case of a cube, each face (quad) should have a normal vector (meaning each vertex of a quad should have the same normal). So just specify an appropriate normal vector before drawing the four vertices of a face (similar to how you specify the colors). In your case these should be (0,0,1) for the front, (1,0,0) for left, (0,0,-1) for back, (-1,0,0) for right, (0,1,0) for top and (0,-1,0) for bottom.

Second, you don't draw a top face, you have two bottom faces (you forgot to set y=1 for the top).

Third, it is good practice to order the vertices of the faces of an object consistently, so that all faces are oriented all counter-clockwise or all clockwise when viewed from the outside (actually you define what the outside is by this orientation), but not some this way and others that way. Allthough in your current configuration this doesn't do any harm, you will get problems once you enable backface-culling (a very common and easy to use optimization technique) or try to compute the face normals automatically.

If this is all crazy talk for you, then delve a little deeper into OpenGL and computer graphics in general.

Comment: +1 for the top face.
What is wrong with the order : Front->Left->Back->Right Top->Bottom Appears counterclockwise to me!

Comment: I don't mean that order. I mean the order of the vertices of an individual face. These should always be ordered the same for all faces (either clockwise or counter-clockwise, if viewed from the outside). But the main error are the missing normals, anyway.